# Erro em código: O servidor cometeu uma violação de protocolo. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Tags: c#

Quando executo essa linha de código para acessar uma URL recebo a mensagem. O servidor cometeu uma violação de protocolo. Section=ResponseStatusLine. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

`using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        var result = wc.DownloadString("http://192.168.0.100/H"); 
                    }`

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro ocorre porque o servidor está entregando um cabeçalho HTTP mal formado.

Na documentação HTTP 1.1 seção 6.1 está escrito:

> ### 6.1 Linha de status
>
> A primeira linha de uma mensagem de resposta é a linha de status, que consiste na versão do protocolo seguida por um
> código numérico de status e sua frase textual associada, com cada
> elemento separado por caracteres SP. Nenhum CR ou LF é permitido,
> exceto na sequência final do CRLF.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html

Alguns servidores entregam os cabeçalhos cujos as linhas terminam ou com `CR` ou `LF` o que acaba gerando esse erro de validação.

Para contornar esse problema você terá que configurar suas requisições para que ignorem a validação dos cabeçalhos HTTP.

Para fazer isso você deve editar seu arquivo `.config`. Lembrando que é `web.config` se a aplicação for servidor e `app.config` se a aplicação for desktop.

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

A propriedade [`HttpWebRequestElement.UseUnsafeHeaderParsing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.configuration.httpwebrequestelement.useunsafeheaderparsing?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Configuration_HttpWebRequestElement_UseUnsafeHeaderParsing) determina o intuito de ignorar, ou não, erros de validação que ocorrem durante a análise de HTTP.

Enquanto estiver definida como `false` as seguintes validações serão executadas durante a análise http:

- Em código de fim de linha, use CRLF; Não é permitido usar CR ou LF sozinho.
- Os nomes de cabeçalhos não devem ter espaços.
- Se houver várias linhas de status, todas as linhas de status adicionais serão tratadas como pares de nome/valor de cabeçalho malformados.
- A linha de status deve ter uma descrição de status, além de um código de status.

Essa configuração não afeta a emissão de erro caso os nomes de cabeçalho que contenham caracteres não ASCII neles.

Comment: Perdoe a ignorância mas eu devo anexar seu código nesse ponto ? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
 </startup>

  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  
</configuration>

Comment: Isso mesmo. referência: [Esquema de configurações Web](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/web/index), [Esquema de arquivos de configuração para o .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/index)

Comment: Desculpe a demora em comentar, mas fiz esse procedimento e o erro continua. Alguma sugestão do motivo do erro continuar ?

Comment: Na documentação do [WebClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8) é recomendado que use a classe [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8), faça a tentativa. Se não der certo coloque uma cópia dos cabeçalhos http na pergunta(pegue com o chrome na aba network dentro das ferramentas do desenvolvedor).